# How to take screenshot and share using react-native?

Tags: react-native, screenshot

I have used react-native-view-shot to take screenshots which return screenshot local URL. and used react-native-share to share on other apps like whats-app etc.
But how can share screenshot because react-native-view-shot give only local path.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to get the base64 of your image. Unless they've updated things, I have used a [workaround I found in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802956/getting-the-base64-of-an-image-from-cameraroll)